# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, routes

When trying to call an ASP.NET method from the client using **$.ajax** it gives the following error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 ()" knowing that the client and the API are both running on the same domain "localhost:4500", I followed the procedure I found in this Microsoft docs "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-javascript?view=aspnetcore-5.0 " and added the wwwroot folder to avoid the CORS issue but still can't call the API methods through the **$.ajax** method in javascript.

I tested the backend code through swagger and it was working just fine.

this my backend controller code:

```
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[Controller]")]
    public class RunAnalysisController : ControllerBase
    {        
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            return Ok();
        }
        [HttpPost("LoadFramesData")]
        public IActionResult LoadFrameData([FromBody]RootObject ModelData)
        {
            try
            {      
                ManageModel.CreateModel(ModelData);
                return Ok(ModelData); //returning same object for testing purpose
            }
            catch
            {
                return BadRequest("Error");
            }
        }
    }
```

and this my ajax function in the client side:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "api/RunAnalysis/LoadFramesData",                   ///// URL must be specified
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(new RootData()), //this class returns a json object
        cache: false,      
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function (ex) {
            WriteToConsole(ex.responseText);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Which Asp.net core Version you are using, or using asp.net 5? From your code, it looks that you just add an API controller in the MVC application, if that is the case, there is no need to enable CROS.

Comment: Are you able to access other action methods in the same controller ?

Comment: the version is .net 5, the problem isn't in CORS anymore the problem is I can't still reach the URL added in the ajax function.

Comment: and i can't access the get method also

Comment: when i debug the javascript code it gets to the $.ajax function and then skips it

Comment: What is the response header? Could you provide it?

Comment: when I debug the javascript code it skips the $.ajax function so there is no request sent or response received

Comment: You could use the debug tool of chrome or edge.

Comment: I have created a sample to test your code, the Ajax function works well, check [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRH2V.gif). You could refer it and try to change the url as below:` url: "/api/RunAnalysis/LoadFramesData", `.  Besides, try to use Postman to validate that when using the post method whether the API action works well or not.

Comment: @ZhiLv Thank you so much, it works just fine after the edits

Comment: Hi @A.Dawood, glad to hear it did help resolve the problem. And I add it as an answer, hoping it can help other community members quickly fix similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the issue relates the request url, change the url as below: `url: "/api/RunAnalysis/LoadFramesData`.

More detail information, you could refer the following sample:

Model:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

MVC View Page:

```
<input type="button" id="btnsubmit" value="Click Me" />
@section Scripts{ 
<script>
     $(function () {
        // LoadChart(); 
        class RootData {
            constructor(id, name) {
                this.ID = id;
                this.Name = name;
            }
        }
        $("#btnsubmit").click(function () {
            //var data = {};
            //data.ID = "1001";
            //data.Name = "Tom"; 
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/api/todo/LoadFramesData",                   ///// URL must be specified 
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify(new RootData(1001, "Tom")), //this class returns a json object
                cache: false,
                success: function (result) {
                    alert(result.name);
                },
                error: function (ex) {
                    alert(ex.responseText);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
}
```

API upload method:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class TodoController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost("LoadFramesData")]
    public IActionResult LoadFrameData([FromBody] RootObject ModelData)
    {
        try
        { 
            return Ok(ModelData);
        }
        catch
        {
            return BadRequest("Error");
        }
    }
```

The result as below:

[image]